# nDepend - get filtered assemblies to analyze

Tags: ndepend

I am using nDepend and I wonder how can I tell nDepend that I'd like to analyze assemblies which names start with specfiic string (Test for example). What I see is that I need to provide full names of the assemblies and I cannot use any sort of wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

- NDepend Start Page
- Analyze VS Solutions and VS Projects
- Select a VS solution file
- then on the up-right corner of the DataGridView use the filter capabilities (shown in screenshot below)

[image: NDepend filter assemblies to analyze by name pattern]

Comment: This option only filters assemblies which should be attached to the nDepend project. What I am looking for is a way to tell nDepend that when it starts analyzes, it should take all assemblies from folders X,Y,Z which (for example) start with MyCompany string (like MyCompany.Web.dll, MyCompany.Domain.dll etc).

Comment: Then you should use develop a program based on NDepend.API, that build a NDepend project by filling it with assemblies satisfying your constraints, and then call RunAnalysis(). You can get inspired from PowerTools source code available in the NDepend redistributable. http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html

Comment: Notice this NDepend.API method that will tell you if a particular file is actually an assembly. http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.DotNet.IDotNetManager~IsAssembly.html